# meteor flow router and template level subscription query

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I have working code which has a list of posts on my `postsList` template which iterates a `postItem` template in a `{{#each}}` block. When this template loads I am subscribed to all posts known as `posts.public`. When the user clicks a link on a post in the list, it routes the URL to `/posts/:_id` and then displays the single post on `postPage` which simply renders the `postItem` template. This should be based on a subscription to `post.single`.

It works, however I don't believe I have it set up correctly in terms of template level subscriptions.

Here is what I have:

**router.js**

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'mainLayout',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('body', {main: 'postsList'});
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/post/:_id', {
  name: 'Post.show',
  action(params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('body', {main: 'postPage'});
  }
});
```

For the `postsList` template I subscribe to all posts and also use a helper for the `{{#each}}` iterator:

**posts-list.js**

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
  posts() {
    return Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
  },
});

Template.postsList.onCreated(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('posts.public');
});
```

For my `postPage` template, designed to render just the single post, I am using another `{{#each}}` block although there must be a better way, as I feel like I'm iterating over one result for the sake of being able to use a helper function:

**post-page.html**

```
<template name="postPage">
  <div class="post-page page">
  {{#each post}}
    {{> postItem}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The below js for `postPage` is where I believe I have the issue. I don't think the subscription is working correctly. My intention is to only subscribe to one post when this template is created. However, I've found that all posts are available and I have to specify in the `post` helper function the specific id of the post I want to return.

**post-page.js**

```
Template.postPage.onCreated( function() {
  let postId = FlowRouter.current().params._id;
  Meteor.subscribe('post.single', postId);
});

Template.postPage.helpers({
  post() {
    let postId = FlowRouter.current().params._id;
    return Posts.find({_id: postId});
  },
});
```

My publishing code is here:

**posts.js**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('posts.public', function () {
    return Posts.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  });

  Meteor.publish('post.single', function (postId) {
    check (postId, String);
    if ( postId ) {
      return [Posts.find( {_id: postId } )];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

So to recap, the code works, however I don't believe I am publishing/subscribing correctly as I am relying on the helper function to return the specific post, rather than the subscription itself only returning one result. Also, I feel like having a `{{#each}}` block to iterate one item just isn't right, but don't know of any alternative.

Comment: There is {{#with}} to change context. It's in the docs. Also if you don't want to loop one item you could change the find in the helper with findOne.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the issue of what is being published right? If all posts are published but my helper is on the client side then all the posts are still open to the client

Comment: Yes, a user can still get all the posts but by default will only get the one. If you want to publish only cerrtain posts you should maybe check for author equals current user on server side or something similar

Comment: You may want to track the subscription's ready state. Kadira has a [tutorial](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-blaze) that deals with your exact situation.

Comment: Have you removed the autopublish package from your project? If not this will publish all posts regardless of your subscriptions. It's enabled by default for faster development

Comment: @MasterAM - Awesome. Many thanks, I think I'd read every post on that site except for the one you linked to. Make sense and is now working! :)